# Preserve headers in Angular application

Tags: angular, nginx, preserve, keycloak-gatekeeper, louketo-proxy

I'm developing an architecture where my Angular front end connected to a Spring Boot back end and the front end is accessible via NGINX.

Before accessing to my application, the user must be authenticated.

I use Keycloak as Identity manager and keycloak-gatekeeper as a proxy oauth that verify whether the user is authenticated or not.

After a successful authentication, gatekeeper redirects (and sends headers with identity information such as : username, email, roles ...) to my front which is a single page that call the spring boot API to retrieve the information based on the logged user and its role.

The problem is : the API doesn't receive any of these headers sent by the Gatekeeper.

I did several test to know where exactly i loose the headers and i found that when i connect the Gatekeeper directly with the API, the API receives all the headers but when i add the angular app in between, the back end receive only standards headers like : host, x-real-ip,x-forwarded-for, access-control-allow-origin ...)

It seems like the front generate a new request -with default headers- to the back and lost the other headers.

How can i preserve those headers so that my API receive them all ?

Here is a picture with my architecture :

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss75B.png)

Thank you all for the help

Comment: Your problem is the redirect. The headers are not sent when you do a redirect.

Comment: You mean the redirect of the Gatekeeper? if so, it works when i redirect directly to the API, i mean the API receives the headers sent by gatekeeper.

Comment: "The problem is : the API doesn't receive any of these headers sent by the Gatekeeper." So does it receive the headers or not ?

Comment: it receives headers when it's connected directly to the gatekeeper but when i put the Angular app in between (so the front who send requests to the API), the API receives only standards headers and not the headers sent by the gatekeeper